# PowerPivot / PivotTable: display Row fields by Field X, but Grand Total by Field Y

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, pivot-table, powerpivot

How can I calculate and display the "Net Book Value" section (bottom 4 rows of second pivot table) using pivot tables / power pivot / calculated fields / measures? It is the sum of records grouped by field: "Group2".

(The pivot table uses "Show Values As": "Running Total In...": Date)

Here's my data:

| Account | AccountName | Date | Amount | Activity | Group1 | Group2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | In-Progress | 08/31/23 | 1100 | Additions | Assets | In-Progress |
| 10 | Furniture | 08/31/23 | 1050 | Additions | Assets | Furniture |
| 15 | Accum Depr – Furniture | 08/31/23 | -70 | Additions | Accumulated Depreciation | Furniture |
| 1 | In-Progress | 09/30/23 | 20 | Additions | Assets | In-Progress |
| 1 | In-Progress | 09/30/23 | -5 | Adjustments | Assets | In-Progress |
| 10 | Furniture | 09/30/23 | 6 | Additions | Assets | Furniture |
| 10 | Furniture | 09/30/23 | -2 | Disposals | Assets | Furniture |
| 15 | Accum Depr – Furniture | 09/30/23 | 2 | Disposals | Accumulated Depreciation | Furniture |
| 15 | Accum Depr – Furniture | 09/30/23 | -9 | Adjustments | Accumulated Depreciation | Furniture |

I have this pivot table now: (NOTE: I can't get this formatted correctly. It looks the same as below just without the bottom rows for "Net Book Value")

| GROUP1 | ACCOUNT | AccountName | Date | Activity |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assets |  |  | 08/31/23 |  |  |  | 09/30/23 |
|  |  |  |  | Additions | Disposals | Adjustments |  |
|  | 1 | In-Progress | 1100 | 20 | 0 | -5 | 1115 |
|  | 10 | Furniture | 1050 | 6 | -2 | 0 | 1054 |
| Assets Total |  |  | 2150 | 26 | -2 | -5 | 2169 |
| Accumulated Depreciation |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 15 | Accum Depr-Furniture | -70 | 0 | 2 | -9 | -77 |
| Accumulated Depreciation Total |  |  | -70 | 0 | 2 | -9 | -77 |
| Grand Total |  |  | 2080 | 26 | 0 | -14 | 2092 |

But I want this:

| GROUP1 | ACCOUNT | AccountName | Date | Activity |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assets |  |  | 08/31/23 |  |  |  | 09/30/23 |
|  |  |  |  | Additions | Disposals | Adjustments |  |
|  | 1 | In-Progress | 1100 | 20 | 0 | -5 | 1115 |
|  | 10 | Furniture | 1050 | 6 | -2 | 0 | 1054 |
| Assets Total |  |  | 2150 | 26 | -2 | -5 | 2169 |
| Accumulated Depreciation |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 15 | Accum Depr-Furniture | -70 | 0 | 2 | -9 | -77 |
| Accumulated Depreciation Total |  |  | -70 | 0 | 2 | -9 | -77 |
| Net Book Value |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 1 | In-Progress | 1100 | 20 | 0 | -5 | 1115 |
|  | 10 | Furniture | 980 | 6 | 0 | -9 | 977 |
| Net Book Value Total |  |  | 2080 | 26 | 0 | -14 | 2092 |

Thanks!